# How to remove specific directory names from path list

Tags: python, django, path

I have a zip files which contains media files, before I extract those files and append the path to my db I need to clean up the path, with extracting the zip.

Path list from zip contains

```
/no-fixed-name/no-fixed-name/images/2012/03/image.jpg
/no-fixed-name/no-fixed-name/images/2012/03/any-image.jpg
/no-fixed-name/no-fixed-name/videos/2012/03/video.mp4
```

I want to strip the path of 1st two directories and get this

```
/images/2012/03/image.jpg
/images/2012/03/any-image.jpg
```

and join `"http://my-cdn-path.com/"` to each path

So far I have done this, but not able to strip it out.

```
import os
import zipfile
import fnmatch

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('samplezip.zip','r')

a = zf.namelist()
search = '*.png'
searchresult = fnmatch.filter(a, search)


for i in searchresult:
   yo = os.path.abspath(i).split(os.sep)[2]
   #This way I can get the dir name that I want to remove but not sure how to do that.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following (treating the path as a string):

```
'http://my-cdn-path.com/' + '/'.join(i.split('/')[-4:]))
```

Or, using os.path:

```
'http://my-cdn-path.com/' + '/'.join(os.path.abspath(i).split(os.sep)[-4:])
```

Comment: Note that `join` does not add a slash to the beginning of the string, so the base URL should end with a slash.

Comment: Made this change. Thanks!